# Question about double integrals and circular segments

Tags: calculus

> Set up a double integral that computes the area inside the unit circle and above the line $y=1/2$ in polar coordinates. $f(x,y)=1$

I've done the Cartesian coordinates but I am unsure of how to set the radius as it changes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please provide more context to your question and show your attempt so we can help. Why would the radius change? Can you show what you did so far?

Comment: Try drawing a picture of the region; see if you can find the spread of the angle $\theta$ and then for $r$ in terms of $\theta$ (the upper bound for $r$ is just $1$).